# How to override Bootstrap 3 navbar margin classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For my personal/professional website:

I'm using Bootstrap 3 CDN and the issue is that I've added a logo to the right of the navbar; the default Bootstrap settings include "margin-left and margin-right set to 0". I've noticed this is causing the logo element "The last element on the right of the picture" to collapse when it's intended to be placed along one line as the left of the navbar and the other navbar items. When I use the Chrome Devtools, I notice that the `margin-left:0` is what is causing the displacement.

My question is: how can I properly override the Bootstrap 3's styles which include --> How can I de-select the `margin-right:0` and set it to `none;`?

```
 @media (min-width: 768px)
    .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container>.navbar-header {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 <!-- language: lang-html -->

          <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

          <!-- language: lang-html -->

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
              </head>
              <body>
                      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                              <div class="container" >
                                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                <div class="navbar-header" >
                                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i id="errorbug" class="fas fa-bug"></i><i id="coffeecup" class="fas fa-coffee"></i>Shamari Hankins</a>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Development</a></li>


                                  </ul>

                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <!-- Right of the NavBar -->
                                    <img  class="shadowProjectsImg "src="sp.jpg">
                          <li><a href="#">Artwork</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                  </ul>`enter code here`
                                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                      </nav> <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 <!-- language: lang-html -->

          <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

          <!-- language: lang-html -->

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
              </head>
              <body>
                      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                              <div class="container" >
                                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                <div class="navbar-header" >
                                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i id="errorbug" class="fas fa-bug"></i><i id="coffeecup" class="fas fa-coffee"></i>Shamari Hankins</a>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Development</a></li>


                                  </ul>

                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <!-- Right of the NavBar -->
                                    <img  class="shadowProjectsImg "src="sp.jpg">
                          <li><a href="#">Artwork</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                  </ul>`enter code here`
                                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                      </nav>
```

Bootstrap navbar margin issue:

[image]

Comment: Your current code seems to be working fine as it is mate: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/fr2w4zby/11/

Comment: No it isn't , what i meant was that the logo containing the "SP" image, it is appearing lower on the navbar due to bootstraps default class which has the margin-right and left set to 0. When i use the developer tools and unset the margin to none; the navbar displays as i'd like too with all elements responsive and on the same line for any given width on the viewport. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To override anything from Bootstrap, as long as your CSS is called after bootstrap, it should just be calling the class and assigning what ever attributes you want i.e.

```
.someClass {
    attribute-to-change: changedValue;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried using the developer tools to change the bootstrap margins in the navbar. But im not sure which one of the classess is the class i need to change in my css file. When you say the css needs to come after the bootstrap . do you mean the file itself or the styles within the css stylesheet

Comment: I meant within the css stylesheet.